# Calculating perimeter and area of a rectangle

Tags: java

I need to be able to input length and width of a rectangle into a console and calculate its perimeter and area. I have it working other than accepting my inputs for the calculations. I know I'm close, but can't seem to figure it out. Thanks in advance for your help. Keep in mind I'm a novice to put it nicely, so your answers may not make sense to me at first. I cannot get it to calculate the values that I input into the console.

```
package edu.purdue.cnit325_lab1;

public class Rectangle {    
    private static double length;
    private static double width;

    public Rectangle() {
        length=0.0;
        width=0.0;
    }

    public Rectangle(double l, double w) {
        length = l;
        width = w;
    }

    public double FindArea() {
        return length*width;
    }

    public double FindPerim() {
        return length*2 + width*2;
    }   
}

package edu.purdue.cnit325_lab1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestRectangle {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Scanner scanL = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.print("Please enter the length of the rectangle: ");
            double L = scanL.nextDouble();
            Scanner scanW = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.print("Please enter the length of the rectangle: ");
            double W = scanW.nextDouble();
            //int W = scanW.nextInt();
            double RectangleArea;
            Rectangle unitRectangle = new Rectangle(); 
            RectangleArea = unitRectangle.FindArea();
            System.out.println("The area of a unit rectangle is " + RectangleArea);

            double RectanglePermiter;
            Rectangle perimRectangle = new Rectangle();
            RectanglePermiter = perimRectangle.FindPerim();
            System.out.println("The permimiter of the unit rectangle is " + RectanglePermiter);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to tell us what issues are you facing?

Comment: The first part is from the rectangle.java and the second is from the testrectangle.java.

Comment: Of course. That I can see. But what's the issue with your code? How is it not working? Are you getting any error, unexpected output?

Comment: @RohitJain It will not accept and calculate the perimeter and area when I input values in the console while running the program.

Comment: @RohitJain I am getting the same output no matter what input I supply. Please enter the length of the rectangle: 3
Please enter the length of the rectangle: 3
The area of a unit rectangle is 0.0
The permimiter of the unit rectangle is 0.0

Comment: `Rectangle unitRectangle = new Rectangle();` not initialized with l and w

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that you are calling the Rectangle constructore with no arguments thus setting its width and height to zero, you should use

Rectangle unitRectangle = new Rectangle(L,W);

and indeed like the other answer you should use one Scanner instance.

Plus regarding coding style: do not upercase your variable names. Its quite confusing for more "experienced" java developers. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for the input, but according to the assignment, we have to default to a value of zero if no input is provided.  Thank you for the insight on the uppercase issue. I was taught in a previous C# class to use camel casing when assigning names.

Comment: I should have been more specific.  Where are you deriving unitRectangle from?

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it. I knew I was close, but being brand new to coding I wasn't sure what I was missing. Thank you very much for assisting me.

Comment: If you want default values, use scanner.hasNextDouble(), if true obtain the double by netDouble() otherwise use 0 as value. So something like double d = scanner.hasNextDouble() ? scanner.nextDouble(): 0.0;

Answer (score 5):

you missed to call `parameterized constructor`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanL = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the length of the rectangle: ");
    double L = scanL.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Please enter the length of the rectangle: ");
    double W = scanL.nextDouble();


    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(l,w); 
    double rectangleArea = rectangle .FindArea();
    System.out.println("The area of a unit rectangle is " + rectangleArea);

    double rectanglePermiter = rectangle.FindPerim();
    System.out.println("The permimiter of the unit rectangle is " + rectanglePermiter);
}
```

Note: Unnecessarily you created two `Scanner` objects and two `Rectangle` objects in your code,which are removed from the above code.

Comment: This fixed it, but since user2721119 posted first I had to accept his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use one Scanner instance. Just reuse it.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.print("Please enter the length of the rectangle: ");
double L = scanner.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Please enter the length of the rectangle: ");
double W = scanner.nextDouble();
```

**Update:** You don't pass the `L` and `W` to the constructor as the other answer points out. However, some mistakes you made:

- You declared `length` and `width` as `static`. Don't do that. That makes no sense. The length and the width are properties of a rectangle and shouldn't be shared by all rectangle instances.
- You don't use the correct naming conventions: variables start with a lowercase character, class names start with an uppercase character.
- You are creating two instances of your Rectangle to calculate both perimeter and area of the same rectangle. Share that instance instead.

Comment: @MartinCourtreaux I have done so, but it still produces the same results. Please enter the length of the rectangle: 3
Please enter the length of the rectangle: 3
The area of a unit rectangle is 0.0
The permimiter of the unit rectangle is 0.0

Comment: You are not passing the width and height of the rectangle you read to the constructor.

Comment: @MartinCourteaux, I thought that was an issue, but I didn't know how to remedy it since I'm using two constructors(if that's the right terminology) of RectangleArea and RectanglePerimiter.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to set the values in some way... you can do either

A)

```
Rectangle unitRectangle = new Rectangle(l,w);
```

B)

or create getters and setters in the rectangle class..

```
setLength(double l) length = l;
setWidth(double w) width = w

double getLength() return length;
double getWidth() return height;
```

Since you are initializing with the default constructor

aka

```
 Rectangle unitRectangle = new Rectangle();
```

the values for length and width will also be zero.

Answer (score 0):

Your code consists of the Default constructor, which will initialize the respective values length and width to `0.0` as set by you and also consist of parametrized constructor which requires input values to be provided and will set the value accordingly.

When you are creating the object of your class, you are calling the Default Constructor instead of parametrized constructor in this line

`Rectangle unitRectangle = new Rectangle();`

Thus setting them to 0.0

If you do Something like this

`Rectangle unitRectangle2 = new Rectangle(2.3,4.3);`

This will create the object having values for length and breadth as 2.3 and 4.3 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
//write a java program which will calculate area and perimeter of rectangle by accepting radius from cmd prompt
//area = width x height,perimeter = (2 x width) + (2 x height)

class AreaAndPerOfRect
{
    int h,w;
    void set(int x,int y)
    {
        h=x;
        w=y;
    }
    int AreaOfRect()
    {
        int area=w*h;
        return area;
    }
    int PerOfRect()
    {
        int per=(2*w)+(2*h);
        return per;
    }
    void disp()
    {
        int area=AreaOfRect();
        System.out.println("area of rectangle"+area);
        int per=PerOfRect();
        System.out.println("area of rectangle"+per);
    }
}
class AreaAndPerOfRectDemo
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        if(args.length!=2)
        {
            System.out.println("please enter two values");
        }
        else
        {
            int x=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            int y=Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            AreaAndPerOfRect ap=new AreaAndPerOfRect();
            ap.set(x,y);
            ap.disp();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//This is the Java code for finding the area and perimeter of a rectangle
package demo;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class DemoTranslation {
public static int area(int length, int width) {
    int areaOfRectangle;
    areaOfRectangle = length * width;
    System.out.println("Area of Rectangle is : " + areaOfRectangle);
    return 0;
}

public static int perimeter(int length, int width) {
    int perimeterOfRectangle;
    perimeterOfRectangle = (length + width) * 2;
    System.out.println("Perimeter of Rectangle is : " + perimeterOfRectangle);
    return 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int length, width, choice;
    System.out.println("Enter the length of the triangle ");
    length = STDIN_SCANNER.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the width of the triangle ");
    width = STDIN_SCANNER.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter 1 : View the area ");
    System.out.println("Enter 2 : View the perimeter ");
    System.out.println("Enter 3 : view both ");
    choice = STDIN_SCANNER.nextInt();
    switch(choice) {
    case 1:
        area(length, width);
        break;
    case 2:
        perimeter(length, width);
        break;
    case 3:
        area(length, width);
        perimeter(length, width);
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid option ");
        break;
    }
    }

    public final static Scanner STDIN_SCANNER = new Scanner(System.in);
    }
```

Comment: This is the program to find the area and perimeter of a rectangle in JAVA, down below written in c too.