# Calculating Area, Length and Width of a Rectangle - Java

Tags: java

I know there was a similar thread:

[Calculating perimeter and area of a rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497458/calculating-perimeter-and-area-of-a-rectangle?rq=1)

but I still do not know what to do.

```
public class Rectangle {

double length, height, rectArea; // assigning variables for length, height and area of the rectangle

Point ul; // assigning variables for all corners
Point ur;
Point lr;
Point ll;

Rectangle(Point p_ul, Point p_ur, Point p_lr, Point p_ll) { //constructor assigning Point variables 
    ul = p_ul;
    ur = p_ur;
    lr = p_lr;
    ll = p_ll;        
}

Rectangle(int x_ul, int y_ul, int x_ur, int y_ur, int x_lr, int y_lr, int x_ll, int y_ll) { //constructor assigning coordinates for each corner Point variable
    ul = new Point (x_ul, y_ul);
    ur = new Point (x_ur, y_ur);
    lr = new Point (x_lr, y_lr);
    ll = new Point (x_ll, y_ll);        
}

public double rectArea() {
    double length = Math.sqrt( (ur.getX()-ul.getX()) * (ur.getX()-ul.getX()) ) + ( (ur.getY()-ul.getY()) * (ur.getY()-ul.getY()) ); //calculates length
    double height = Math.sqrt( (ur.getX()-lr.getX()) * (ur.getX()-lr.getX()) ) + ( (ur.getY()-lr.getY()) * (ur.getY()-lr.getY()) ); //calculates height

    return(length * height);
}

void displayInfo() { //Print statements   
    System.out.println("Rectangle Info: ");
    System.out.println("Upper Left Point (x,y) : (" + ul.getX() + "," + ul.getY() + ")");
    System.out.println("Upper Right Point (x,y) : (" + ur.getX() + "," + ur.getY() + ")");
    System.out.println("Lower Left Point (x,y) : (" + ll.getX() + "," + ll.getY() + ")");
    System.out.println("Lower Right Point (x,y) : (" + lr.getX() + "," + lr.getY() + ")");        
    System.out.println("Area: " + rectArea);
    System.out.println("Length: " + length);
    System.out.println("Height: " + height);
    System.out.println("ur-lr(Y): " + (ur.getY()-lr.getY()));// this prints 4
    System.out.println("ur-lr(X): " + (ur.getX()-lr.getX()));// this prints 0
}    
}
```

I am not sure why when I call the length and height with the actual ul.get(X) etc I get the correct output of length and height but when I print "length" and "height" I just get 0 and therefore making my Area 0.

As you most likely can tell I am a n00b. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your `length` and `height` variables in the `rectArea()` method are local variables -- you're not writing to the instance variables of the same names.

Comment: you have to remove the double KW, for length&height at rectArea(), AND you need to assign the value to rectArea using rectArea(): rectArea = rectArea(); you can add it to the constructors, last line

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 local variables with the same names as instance variables. This is called shadowing the variables. Therefore when you call them through the methods you are getting correct results. But your instance variables are not been initialized. So they are having their default double values which i s 0.0

Change your method like this

```
public double rectArea() {
    length = Math.sqrt((ur.getX()-ul.getX()) * (ur.getX()-ul.getX())) + ((ur.getY()-ul.getY()) * (ur.getY()-ul.getY())); //calculates length
    height = Math.sqrt((ur.getX()-lr.getX()) * (ur.getX()-lr.getX())) + ((ur.getY()-lr.getY()) * (ur.getY()-lr.getY())); //calculates height

    return(length * height);
}
```

Comment: I changed that but it is calculating the wrong height. I have two coordinates in my method ur: (5,5) and lr: (5,1) and it is telling me distance between those 2 points is 16 (when it should be 4). The length is giving me the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling rectArea() method, you tried using the variables directly which were not computed.
Here's the corrected program:

```
import java.awt.Point;
public class Rectangle {

double length, height, rectArea; // assigning variables for length, height and area of the rectangle

Point ul; // assigning variables for all corners
Point ur;
Point lr;
Point ll;

Rectangle(Point p_ul, Point p_ur, Point p_lr, Point p_ll) { //constructor assigning Point variables 
    ul = p_ul;
    ur = p_ur;
    lr = p_lr;
    ll = p_ll;        
}

Rectangle(int x_ul, int y_ul, int x_ur, int y_ur, int x_lr, int y_lr, int x_ll, int y_ll) { //constructor assigning coordinates for each corner Point variable
    ul = new Point (x_ul, y_ul);
    ur = new Point (x_ur, y_ur);
    lr = new Point (x_lr, y_lr);
    ll = new Point (x_ll, y_ll);        
}

public double rectArea() {
    length = Math.sqrt( (ur.getX()-ul.getX()) * (ur.getX()-ul.getX())  + (ur.getY()-ul.getY()) * (ur.getY()-ul.getY()) ); //calculates length
    height = Math.sqrt( (ur.getX()-lr.getX()) * (ur.getX()-lr.getX())  + (ur.getY()-lr.getY()) * (ur.getY()-lr.getY()) ); //calculates height

    return(length * height);
}

void displayInfo() { //Print statements   
    System.out.println("Rectangle Info: ");
    System.out.println("Upper Left Point (x,y) : (" + ul.getX() + "," + ul.getY() + ")");
    System.out.println("Upper Right Point (x,y) : (" + ur.getX() + "," + ur.getY() + ")");
    System.out.println("Lower Left Point (x,y) : (" + ll.getX() + "," + ll.getY() + ")");
    System.out.println("Lower Right Point (x,y) : (" + lr.getX() + "," + lr.getY() + ")"); 
    rectArea = rectArea();
    System.out.println("Area: " + rectArea);
    System.out.println("Length: " + length);
    System.out.println("Height: " + height);
    System.out.println("ur-lr(Y): " + (ur.getY()-lr.getY()));// this prints 2
    System.out.println("ur-lr(X): " + (ur.getX()-lr.getX()));// this prints 0
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Rectangle rr = new Rectangle(1,3,3,3,3,1,1,1);
    rr.displayInfo();
}
}
```

Comment: I added your changes and Thusitha Thilina Dayaratn's correction above and I described in his comment that I am getting an incorrect height.

Comment: corrected the program, had problem in parentheses in rectArea method